# ID3v1 tag in MP3 format

Tags: c++, mp3, decoding, id3

I am trying (or just started) to write music player from scratch (starting with MP3 format) and thus I have a question about the ID3v1/1.1 tag.
Let's take a field from the tag, let's say, song title. It has 30 characters (bytes) and there is my question, is '\0' already counted in it or do I have to add another byte for null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As all artists doesn't have a 30 character name it is said that if there is some bytes left after the information is entered in the field, those bytes should be fille with the binary value 0.

See [ID3v1-Spec](http://id3.org/ID3v1).

I would say, the same principle can be applied to the other fields(title, album,...).

Comment: I have read that before posting, the quote only says that if there is less characters than a field has 'allocated', rest will be filled with null.
I should have specified my question better:
Is there a possibility that let's say title will be filled with all 30 characters(different than null) or only 29 with last reserved for null?

Comment: If you've got more than 30 characters -> trim them to 30 characters. If you've got 30 characters, there is no need to escape them. If you've got less than 30 characters -> escape them.

Comment: The fields can be filled with 30 actual characters, and then they are not 0-terminated. Moreover, keep in mind that not all files actually conform to the spec - often the fields are padded with <space> rather than 0. In short, you must 0-terminate strings yourself.